# Webview crash on real devices

Tags: android, android-webview

`WebView` working fine on emulator but on real phone devices its crash.
I do not have any code in Java code , just i have WebView tag in layout xml file.

*XML code*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.webviewtest.MainActivity" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*JAVA Code*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

}

Comment: logcat please share.

Comment: post your logcat crash message

Comment: if this is the only code that you have, then it is impossible to crash.